# How to get value of an custom attribute using asset:get tag

Tags: webcenter-sites

My application has a page attribute to store the page title. while writing the site plan, I am loading the page asset using asset:load by ID field. In the same way i want to get the value from "PageTitle" page attribute using asset:get instead of assetset: tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible Mandava. The assetset api was built for handle flex assets. asset:get handles basic asset attributes like id, startdate, enddate..

Answer (score 0):

Use asset:scatter tag and access the flex attributes using the Attribute_<Attribute name> format using ics:getvar or ics.GetVar().

```
Ex: <ics:getvar name="Attribute_PageTitle" />
```